# Ethers.js gives "resolver or addr is not configured for ENS name"

Tags: yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ethereum, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I have the following code:

```js
const ethereumProvider = ethers.getDefaultProvider(ETHEREUM_RPC);

const contract = new ethers.Contract(
  CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
  abi,
  ethereumProvider,
);
```

The [ethers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethers) package gives me the following error:

> Error: resolver or addr is not configured for ENS name (argument="name", value="734574864865375122901309634679882622222228500042", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.5.0)

I don't know where this number comes from. I never give this as an argument anywhere.

Also, this error only occurs when deployed on AWS Beanstalk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the "weird number" was the decimal version of the smart contract address (which should be hexadecimal).

The hexadecimal to decimal conversion happened in the YAML file where I pass the environment variables because the value was a number and not a string.

```yaml
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    CONTRACT_ADDRESS=0x80ab79e5c36351Fb5DBe2b35E97f724EcA47AE4A
```

So I just needed to surround the value with double quotes:

```yaml
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    CONTRACT_ADDRESS="0x80ab79e5c36351Fb5DBe2b35E97f724EcA47AE4A"
```

Answer (score 9):

I think this error is usually associated with the contract address being passed as parameter.

For me, I got the error because I was passing an empty string instead of a contract address.